# What are PackageReferences and how will they help optimise the way I deal with NuGet packages?

Tags: nuget

With version 9.1, Sitecore changed their NuGet library to no longer include `NoReferences` versions of their assemblies. This is also mentioned in [How do I reference Sitecore binaries from NuGet?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/168/how-do-i-reference-sitecore-binaries-from-nuget).

One alternative being brought up, is to shift to using `PackageReferences` (applicable only to VS2017 and above). What is that?  And what would be involved in making the switch?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`PackageReference` is a new way to allow NuGet to manage your projects references. Before this, adding a NuGet package would update both the `packages.config` file and the `.csproj` file for your solution. The `packages.config` contains the package name and version, and the `.csproj` file contains a reference to the downloaded package on disk.

### Enter `PackageReference`

From VS2017 you can now use the `PackageReference` node to manage NuGet dependencies directly within the `.csproj` file. This still uses other aspects of NuGet like the `nuget.config` file, all those settings are still applied.

Because of this, you get a lot more control over your NuGet dependencies. For example, you can use MSBuild conditions to choose package references per target framework, configuration, platform etc...

### Adding a PackageReference

To add a package reference, you just need to add it to the project file like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
    <PackageReference Include="Sitecore.Kernel" Version="12.0.0" />
    <!-- ... -->
</ItemGroup>
```

You can specify the version. If you specify a specific number, that means that it is `>=12.0.0`. The preference is on the lowest version that meets that requirement.

One very cool thing is [Floating Versions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution#floating-versions). With floating version you can do things like "use the latest 12.0.x version". For example:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
    <PackageReference Include="Sitecore.Kernel" Version="12.0.*" />
    <!-- ... -->
</ItemGroup>
```

### Benefits of using PackageReference

- **You can manage all your project dependencies in one place**
- **Easier to see your projects actual dependencies** - With `PackageReference`, you only add direct dependencies to your `.csproj` file. If a NuGet package has dependencies, they do not clutter up your project file anymore.
- **Performance** - `PackageReference` packages are saved to a `global-packages` folder instead of a local solution folder. Uses less disk space, is a bit faster when you already have packages downloaded. See [Managing the global packages and cache folders](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders)
- **Control over dependencies and content flow** using the MSBuild conditions as mentioned above

### Packages.config is not being developed

One big benefit of moving to this way of handling NuGet packages is that the existing `packages.config` is no longer under active development, whereas `PackageRefrence` is https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6763

### Migrating to PackageReference

There is a way in VS to migrate existing `packages.config` setups to `PackageReference`. In your **Solution Explorer**, right-click on the **References** node or the `packages.config` file and click **Migrate packages.config to PackageReference**

This should migrate you over to `PackageReference` - but there are known issues with that. See here for details on the known issues [Migrate from packages.config to PackageReference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference)

There is also a `NuGet PackageReference Updater` tool on the VS market place: [NuGet PackageReference Updater](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CloudNimble.NuGetPackageReferenceUpgrader)

### Conclusion

`PackageReference` is the future and has a number of benefits over `packages.config`. Its worth looking into migrating your projects, but just be aware that there are some limitations with existing packages, especially Sitecore modules like Glass and Unicorn that include example config files. They will need updates to fully support that with `PackageReference`, so hopefully that will happen soon.

#### Some references:

- [Migrate to PackageReference with 3 clicks](https://blog.nuget.org/20180409/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference.html)
- [Migrate from packages.config to PackageReference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference)
- [Package references (PackageReference) in project files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files)

Comment: It should be noted that the built in migration is not available to ASP.NET projects, those will require the VS extension.

Comment: There are still a bunch of package conflicts (though it's just a warning) and version issues. Any decent way to clean that up? I have projects telling me there are conflicts between versions of System.Linq for projects that dont even reference it directly.